# Can't enter 2nd page from menu after having entered a page prior

Tags: c

After entering the 1st or 2nd page, and returning back to the menu, I can only access the 1st page and not the 2nd page.

I've tried putting fflush(stdin) before every string and character input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int password, i, j, timesVisited;
    char name[10][15]={"jay"}, address[10][40]={"singapore"}, ic[10][12], gender[10][6], contact[10][11]={"010"}, dataToEdit[8], patientToEdit[20], newData[40], menuOption, returnOption;


while(returnOption!=2){
    //Menu
    puts("Menara Clinic\n");
    puts("Press 1 to add patients' info");
    puts("Press 2 to edit patients' info");
    puts("Press 3 to access patients' history");
    puts("Press 4 to access inventory");
    puts("Press 5 to delete patients' info"); fflush(stdin);

    scanf("%c", &menuOption);
    //menuOption = getch();
    system("cls");

    //Page 1
    if(menuOption=='1')
    do
    {   for(i=0; i<1; i++)                                      //CHANGE i VALUE TO 10 AFTER TESTING
        {   printf("Enter name: "); fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", name[i]);
            printf("Enter gender: "); fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", gender[i]);
            printf("Enter address: "); fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", address[i]);
            printf("Enter contact no: "); fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", contact[i]);
            printf("Enter IC: "); fflush(stdin);
            scanf("%s", ic[i]);

            putchar('\n');
            puts("Press 0 to continue");
            puts("Press 1 to return to menu"); fflush(stdin);
            returnOption = getch();
        }
    }while(returnOption=='0');
    if(returnOption=='1')
    {   system("cls");
        continue;
    }

    //Page 2
    else if(menuOption=='2')
    {   do{
        i=0;
        printf("Enter name: "); fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%s", patientToEdit);
        for(i; i<1; i++)                                        //CHANGE i VALUE TO 10 AFTER TESTING
            {   if(strcmp(name[i], patientToEdit)==0)
                {   printf("Enter data to edit: "); fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%s", dataToEdit);

                    if(strcmp(dataToEdit,"address")==0)
                    {   printf("Enter new address: "); fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s", newData);
                        strcpy(address[i], newData);    
                        printf("%s's new address is now %s\n", name[i], address[i]);                    
                    }
                    else if(strcmp(dataToEdit,"contact")==0)
                    {   printf("Enter new contact no: "); fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%s", newData);
                        strcpy(contact[i], newData);
                        printf("%s's new contact no is now %s\n", name[i], contact[i]); 
                    }
                }
            }
            putchar('\n');
            puts("Press 0 to continue");
            puts("Press 1 to return to menu"); fflush(stdin);
            returnOption = getch();
        }while(returnOption=='0');
        if(returnOption=='1')
        {   system("cls");
            continue;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The program should allow you to enter any of the pages from the menu even after already having accessed a page before.

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` does nothing

Comment: You do realise that `scanf("%s", ...)` stops scanning at the first whitespace? It's unlikely that "name" or "address" have no whitespace. Any remaining input remains buffered and is supplied to the next `scanf` entry. On the other hand, you've taken no steps to protect the string buffers from overflow.

Comment: You removed your remarks on my answer, is it ok now ? do you understand the advantage of the space before `%c` in _scanf_ now ?

Comment: @bruno I think I somewhat get the concept, but the program still isn't working unfortunately.

Comment: @WanLuqmanHakeem I just edited my answer, see it again, you have 2 errors associated with returnOption

Comment: @bruno Alright it's working now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @WanLuqmanHakeem you also have a problem of logic because you do not test the value of _returnOption_ into the for (I just edited my andwer)

Comment: regarding: `fflush(stdin)`  The C standard specifically states that this statement results in undefined behavior.  (Sadly, visual studio does not follow the C standard, so actually has an implemention for `fflush()` that allows for input streams)

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing.  Amongst other problems, the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <stdlib.h>` for the function: `system()`

Comment: regarding: `returnOption = getch();`  the function: `getch()` is not portable.  Suggest using: `getchar()`

Comment: the function: `getch()` is defined in: `conio.h` and the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <conio.h>`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding:  1) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", dataToEdit);`  When calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  They return the number of successful input format conversions.  2) when using the input format specifiers: '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids a buffer overflow and the resulting undefined behavior

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", dataToEdit);`  The input format specifiers '%s' stops inputting data bytes when it encounters any 'white space', like a space or tab or newline.

Comment: please vertically align statements that are at the same indent level  Otherwise we have to 'edit' your code to determine what statements go together

Comment: the posted code is missing several closing braces '}',

Comment: suggest making the menu code into a separate function(s) that can be called as needed

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", &menuOption);`  This could be inputting a leftover '\n' in `stdin`  A way to avoid that problem is to modify the format string to: `" %c"`  as the leading space will result in any 'white space' left in `stdin` to be consumed before inputting the next char of interest

Comment: when asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, then post code that (cleanly) compiles so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: regarding: `puts("Press 1 to return to menu"); 
            fflush(stdin);
            returnOption = getch();`  then prompt is output the the 'stdin' is flushed, then the response is input.   This very likely to consume the response before the `getch()` can get it.  Suggest: `fflush(stdin);  puts("Press 1 to return to menu"); returnOption = getch();`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> ```
> char name[10][15]={"jay"},..., menuOption, returnOption;
>
>  while(returnOption!=2){
> ```

there are two errors :

- you missed to initialize *returnOption* so the behavior is undefined when you test it the first time
- you want to compare with '2' rather than with 2, so do `while(returnOption!='2')` rather than `while(returnOption!=2)`

Also :

- replace `scanf("%c", &menuOption);` by `scanf(" %c", &menuOption);` to bypass spaces and newlines
- replace the two `returnOption = getch();` by `scanf(" %c", &returnOption);`
- and remove all the `fflush(stdin);`because they do nothing, extract from its description :

> For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but
>   **not pipes or terminals**), fflush() discards any buffered data  that  has
>          been fetched from the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the
>          application.

I also strongly encourage you to protect array overflow by limiting the allowed number of char read by `scanf("%s...`, for instance a *name* is memorized on 15 characters (including the null character) so do `scanf("%14s", name[i]);` etc

I do not understand why

> ```
>     putchar('\n');
>     puts("Press 0 to continue");
>     puts("Press 1 to return to menu");
>
>     returnOption = getch();
> ```

is inside the `for(i=0; i<1; i++)` while you do not test the enter value, probably you wanted :

```
//Page 1
if(menuOption=='1')
{
  for(i=0; i<1; i++)                                      //CHANGE i VALUE TO 10 AFTER TESTING
  {
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name[i]);

    printf("Enter gender: ");
    scanf("%s", gender[i]);

    printf("Enter address: ");
    scanf("%s", address[i]);

    printf("Enter contact no: ");
    scanf("%s", contact[i]);

    printf("Enter IC: ");
    scanf("%s", ic[i]);

    putchar('\n');
    puts("enter 1 to return to menu");
    if ((scanf(" %c", &returnOption) == 1) &&
        (returnOption == '1'))
      break;
  }
  system("cls");
}
//Page 2
else if(menuOption=='2')
```

Note you can also do not ask for to continue or not when *i* will be 9

Comment: @WanLuqmanHakeem the space before `%c` bypass space and new lines, the _scanf_ before let the newline you enter

Comment: @WanLuqmanHakeem when you enter the contact you also enter a newline after, because _fflush_ does nothing from a terminal the newline is still available and _getch_ or `scanf("%c..` will get it. This is why you need `scanf(" %c"..` with the space before `%c`